# What counts as a newline for Raku *source* files?

Tags: unicode, comments, newline, raku, rakudo

I was somewhat surprised to observe that the following code

```raku
# comment  say 1;
# comment  say 2;
# comment say 3;
# comment say 4;
```

prints `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.

Here are the relevant characters after "# comment":

```raku
say "  ".uninames.raku;
# OUTPUT: «("PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR", "LINE SEPARATOR", "<control-000B>", "<control-000C>").Seq»
```

Note that many/all of these characters are invisible in most fonts.  At least with my editor, *none* cause the following text to be printed on a new line.  And at least one (`<control-000C>`, aka `Form Feed`, sometimes printed as `^L`) is in fairly wide use in Vim/Emacs as a section separator.

This raises a few questions:

1. Is this intentional, or a bug?
2. If intentional, what's the use-case (other than winning obfuscated code contests!)
3. Is it just these 4 characters, or are there others?  (I found these because they share the [mandatory break](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B:Line_Break=Mandatory_Break:%5D) Unicode property.  Does that property (or some other Unicode property?) govern what Raku considers as a newline?)
4. Just, really, wow.

(I realize #4 is not *technically* a question, but I feel it needed to be said).

Comment: The real problem here is a lack of support for Unicode in other languages and thus other software.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Raku's syntax is defined as a Raku grammar. The rule for parsing such a comment is:

```
token comment:sym<#> {
   '#' {} \N*
}
```

That is, it eats everything after the `#` that is not a newline character. As with all built-in character classes in Raku, `\n` and its negation are Unicode-aware. The [language design docs](https://github.com/Raku/old-design-docs/blob/master/S05-regex.pod#changed-metacharacters) state:

> \n matches a logical (platform independent) newline, not just \x0a. See TR18 section 1.6 for a list of logical newlines.

Which is a reference to the [Unicode standard for regular expressions](https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Line_Boundaries).

I somewhat doubt there was ever a specific language design discussion along the lines of "let's enable all the kinds of newlines in Unicode, it'll be cool!" Rather, the decisions were that Raku should follow the Unicode regex technical report, and that Raku syntax would be defined in terms of a Raku grammar and thus make use of the Unicode-aware character classes. That a range of different newline characters are supported is a consequence of consistently following those principles.

Comment: Interesting.  I _suppose_ that makes sense; there's certainly value in consistently supporting Unicode.  On the other hand, having invisible characters that terminate comments makes Raku trivially vulnerable to the sort of "trojan code" attacks that usually require more complex manipulations of Bidi characters or something. (e.g., https://krebsonsecurity.com/2021/11/trojan-source-bug-threatens-the-security-of-all-code/)

Comment: I guess we just need everyone else to be as grumpy as me in code reviews about left-behind commented out code. :-)